# How to make a button spawn randomly (html)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am making a button that is supposed to be hard to click. I want to prevent reload spoofing (reloading and clicking where the button spawns) by making the button spawn randomly. I tried this with JS but it did not work. Any suggestions? ***Thanks in advance!***

JavaScript:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var thisDiv = divs[i];

    randomTop = getRandomNumber(0, winHeight);
    randomLeft = getRandomNumber(0, winWidth);

    thisDiv.style.top = randomTop + "px";
    thisDiv.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="alertonclick()" class="Rainbow buttonmove notouch button1 btn">Try to click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is thisDiv? where are you adding the div to the document?

Comment: well what is the css position set to? absolute? relative? etc? What is the parent's position? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I am adding the div to the button using the html.

Comment: If your element isn't absolutely positioned, the top and left styles will be ignored.

Comment: @SamiOsman Please show us the relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: @epascarello I didn't set one...I'm bad at css...

Comment: Well there be your problem.

Comment: Ok hold on I will add it.

Comment: How did you get the `divs`?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov what do you mean?

Comment: @SamiOsman, `divs` is not defined in your code

Comment: @s.kuznetsov wait so how would I fix that? (I am new so it is confusing.)

Comment: @SamiOsman, I think it should be like this - `let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');`

Comment: So the randomizer works, but it randomly chooses the distance of the cursor between the button instead of randomizing the button. The website: https://unclickable-button.samiosman.repl.co/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231744/discussion-between-s-kuznetsov-and-sami-osman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `for {}` from your javascript, because only **one** div with a button inside will always be used. And add logic with event `mousemove` to bind the div to the mouse cursor.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div");
var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

randomTop = getRandomNumber(0, winHeight);
randomLeft = getRandomNumber(0, winWidth);

div.style.top = randomTop + "px";
div.style.left = randomLeft + "px";

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;
    div.style.left = x + 10 + "px";
    div.style.top = y + 10 + "px";
});
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="alertonclick()" class="Rainbow buttonmove notouch button1 btn">Try to click me</button>
</div>
```